# My application has stopped working when i start activity using intent

Tags: java, android

when i start getContact activity from another activity then application has stopped. getContact activity worked fine when i write code in mainActivity means no use of intent it will work.i also tried so many solution please help me.

this is getContact Activity

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class getContact extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        //String name=extras.getString("ContactName");
        //String SenderNum=extras.getString("SenderNum");
        String name="Name";
        String number=get(name,getContact.this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number "+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public String get(String name, Context context) {
        String ret=null;
        String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + name +"%'";
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, selection, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            ret = c.getString(0);
        }
        c.close();
        if(ret==null)
            ret = "Unsaved";
        return ret;
    }
}
```

and i am tried to start above activity using following from another activity

```java
 Intent i=new Intent(contactActivity.this,getContact.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
```

And this is the output of logcat when i start activity

```java
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-06-12 09:26:17.399 6361-6361/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6361
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.getContact}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{386669f 6361:com.example.myapplication/u0a335} (pid=6361, uid=10335) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{386669f 6361:com.example.myapplication/u0a335} (pid=6361, uid=10335) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1718)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1671)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4267)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5579)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2280)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1533)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:518)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
        at com.example.myapplication.getContact.get(getContact.java:27)
        at com.example.myapplication.getContact.onCreate(getContact.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6857)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: what is your activity name from where you are starting Intent

Comment: contactActivity

Comment: did you have getContact inside your manifest

Comment: Yes. i declared in manifest using <activity android:name=".getContact"/>

Comment: show me the error you are getting in logcat

Comment: where is `setContentView(R.layout.xxxxx)`?

Comment: Have you added and granted permissions to read/write contacts ?

Comment: i dont want set content view just it toast the output and i granted all permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the error logs it is showing Security Exception, I believe the permissions are not granted.

Add below permissions in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Also if you are targeting devices above Marshamallow you need to consider granting permissions from user.

```
 requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS, WRITE_CONTACTS},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Check if the permissions are already granted with

```
 int result3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_CONTACTS);
 int result4 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_CONTACTS);
```

both values should be 0

Comment: Ok Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are not inflating any layout of your activity. Your onCreate method should call `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)`